# Laravel routing issue. Not working - not defined Error

Tags: php, laravel

I have a `CoolController` which has `callapi` function.

My route is:

```
Route::middleware([
    'derestrictDataAvailability',
    'chooseProduct',
    'web',
    'auth',
    'admin'
])->namespace('Admin')->prefix('admin')->name(
    'admin.'
)->group(
    function () {    
        Route::get(
                '/callcurl/',
                [
                    'as' => 'admin.callcurl',
                    'uses' => 'CoolController@callapi',

                ]

            );}
```

My View is Under `Resources/views/admin/callcurl.blade.php`. But it is not working when I call like this in the other blade:

```
<a href="{{ route('admin.callcurl') }}">
```

Can someone help what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Are you getting any kind of error? If so then please share the error.

Comment: try to remove `->name(
    'admin.'
)`

Comment: route('admin.admin.callcurl') I think it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="{{ route('admin.admin.callcurl') }}">
```

because you are adding admin prefix route,so you need to add prefix in view also.